# Vim shows garbage characters

Tags: vim, plugins

When I start vim with one of these plugins:

- TagBar
- Session

I see sometimes garbage characters in the buffer when I open vim.

Here are these characters:

```
;2R^[[>1;2802;0c
```

By uninstalling these two plugins, I don't see these garbage characters anymore.

If I type `dd`, it does not even delete these characters. Vim says the buffer is empty.

Putting this command at the end of my .vimrc is a workaround for this problem:

```
autocmd VimEnter * redraw!
```

With this, these characters are deleted immediately.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I switched to `neovim` and I've never seen this issue anymore.

Answer (score 10):

Vim asks the terminal for its version, what you're seeing is the response (cp. `:help v:termresponse`). It only appears printed in the terminal; that's why you can't "edit" it and it appears after a redraw.

Why Vim doesn't properly receive it, I don't know. Switching the terminal program might help. You could also try to suppress the query via `:set t_RV=` in your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Switching to `bash` or `sh` does the same thing as `zsh`. And adding this line in my `.vimrc` change the garbage text to `;2R`. Is there anything else I can do? Thanks.

Comment: The shell doesn't influence this, switching to another _terminal_ might help.

Comment: I tried several terminals (mate terminal, sakura, terminator, patheon terminal and gnome terminal) without success. Have you another idea? Thanks.

Comment: Which plugins do you have installed? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: In my case, this was being caused by: `nnoremap <Esc> :noh<CR>`.  Commenting out this line solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ingo! I only get this on the mac, so for me it's

```
   if has('mac')
   :set t_RV=
   endif
```